deepspeed goes wrong after upgrading the transformers version
I am training a VLM model. The codes went well when the transformers version is 4.31. However, when I want to use a different base, which is supported by transformers==4.35. After such upgrading, the codes went wrong by:
enter image description here
Even I change back to original base model under transformers==4.35, the error still exists. How should I approach such problem. I read some pages saying this is because of shortage of memory. But the original setting fails either, upgrading the transformers will increase memory consumption even with the same model?
I tried device_map="auto" in the from_pretrained function. It does not work. Can this be solved without degrading the transformers' version?
